# Not able to click the android Listview after 2-3 clicks on Motorola XT925 device

Tags: android, listview, motorola

I am not able to click the listview after clicking it 2-3 times on Motorola XT925 device.

Steps are as follows:

Click on a listview activity1 and it will redirect to activity2.From activity2, click back  button and it will redirect to activity1.
Repeat the above steps 2-3 times and after that listview is not clickable.

This scenario works on all devices except Motorola XT925 device.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: sometimes I hate to develop for Android for this reason. How did you tested on "all devices"? -there are to much...which ones works exactly, what Android version has they and the XT925 ?

Comment: I have tested it on Samsung Galaxy Note II,Galaxy Nexus Prime,Motorola Milestone,Motorola Droid,Motorola Atrix,Lg Optimus one. Version of Motorola XT925 is 4.0.4.Galaxy Note II and Nexus prime has version 4.0+ and rest of them are 2.3